# Modal bootstrap MVC 5

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5, twitter-bootstrap

Estou tentando usar o modal do `Bootstrap`, mas não consigo fazer a janela abrir em forma de modal com o estilo da pagina, ao invés disso ela abre como uma pagina sem nenhum estilo e usando toda a frame do browser.

**Segue código da pagina:**

```
@model MyApplication.ViewModels.MyViewModel


@Ajax.ActionLink("Adicionar Endereço", "Create", "Enderecos", new { area = "Geografia", id = Model.Id },
    new AjaxOptions() { 
        HttpMethod = "Get", 
        UpdateTargetId = "modalContent", 
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, 
        OnBegin = "onBegin", 
        OnSuccess = "onSuccess", 
        OnFailure = "onFailure", 
        OnComplete = "onComplete" },
    new { id = "btnEndereco", @class = "btn btn-lg btn-info" }
)

<a href='@Url.Action("Create", "Enderecos", new { area = "Geografia", id = Model.Id})' class="btn btn-success btn-xs">Adicionar Endereço</a>

<table id="enderecosJson">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>CEP</th>
            <th>Rua</th>
            <th>Numero</th>
            <th>Complemento</th>
            <th>Bairro</th>
            <th>Estado</th>
            <th>Cidade</th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>


<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content" id="modalContent">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function onBegin() {
            //alert('begin');
        }

        function onSuccess() {
            //alert('success');
        }

        function onComplete() {
            // alert('complete');
            $('#myModal').modal('show');
        }

        function onFailure() {
            alert('fail');
        }
    </script>
}
```

**A tela fica assim:**

[image: endereco]

Alguém pode me dar uma luz onde posso estar errando?

Comment: Como estão os *Bundles* dessa modal? O CSS e o JS são carregados em que momento?

Comment: `<a href='...' class="btn btn-success btn-xs">Adicionar Endereço</a>`  no print está mostrando diferente, pois não tem palavra ou cor verde. Eu estou achando que o seu site não está carregando os arquivos Bootstrap, como o Cigano disse, confere os bundles se estão carregando direito.

Comment: Então gente, descobri que a minha view não esta carregando nada da minha _layout, como nãos sou muito bom em front-end to penando. O que estou tentando fazer é chamar da minha controllerX, a action create da controllerY de modo que a view create da controllerY apareça em forma de modal na minha tela, sem mudar a tela de baixo ( view da controllerX), porém ou isso não é possível e eu terei que criar essa view chamando ela como partial da controllerX, ou vou ter que modificar minha model para atender a esse cadastro, vou fazer os testes sugeridos.

Comment: Fiz uma copia de uma pagina da web que esta funcionando e testei da seguinte maneira, primeiro implementei na pasta controller direta, a pagina da web funcionou como deveria, quando implementei utilizando area, parou de funcionar, alguem sabe o motivo ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Está carregando só o JS do bootstrap, tem que carregar o CSS tambem, faz um teste, coloca essa tag no seu header =

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">`

Comment: vou tentar @henriquedomingospereira